# Excel - SUM Daily results based on given date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

thank you for taking a minute to help me!

I have 3 sheets, 3 of them with daily data of users, vehicles, and population which is steady, all of them have the same structure:
[image]

D column is location and the rest are daily results. Results change every 14 days, that's why for each location you are seeing the same data.

And there's a 4th, where I want to concentrate results from the previous sheets based on data and location - location is D column:
[image]

I want to set both start and end date and based on that, sum daily results by location. For example, suppose that Inicio - Start date is 01/03/2020 and Termino - End Date is 05/03/2020, in the second image, where I highlight SUM HERE it should appear 227,340 for 001-L1 Dr. Galvez N.

I already tried SUMIF, SUMIFS, SUMPRODUCT but it doesn´t seem to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not clear what you want. Do you need to extract a summary for March 1 to March 15? Or just March 1? The numbers don't seem to change but what if they do? Or do you just wish for a horizontal total? Please don't answer in a comment. Modify your question. What's the difference between the 3 sheets? Different sequence of 'Sentido'? If the numbers added up horizontally from each sheet are added to each other will the resulting total make any sense?

Comment: Srry if I´m not making myself clear, I think I have just made the right changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What didn't work with `SUMPRODUCT`? Try this - the result is correct:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$E$3:$M$3>=$E$2)*(Sheet1!$E$3:$M$3<=$F$2)*(Sheet1!$D$2:$D$14=D5)*Sheet1!$E$4:$M$14)
```

I tried to adjust the ranges to your example, but change them if necessary.

[image]

Comment: Well, it returns #Value!

Comment: @RenéMartínez As you can see, in my example, the formula returns a correct result, I assume the problem is in the wrong ranges or in the incorrect data types. Can you share the excel file with sample data (Onedrive or elsewhere)? This will make it easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I checked once again and the headers in my table were in text, I added a second row with date format and it work!

Answer (score 1):

I have developed this formula for you (001). Please take a look.

[E5] `=SUMIFS(INDEX(Counts1,MATCH($D5,Stops1,0),0),Dates1,">=" & $E$2,Dates1,"<=" & $F$2)`

The formula is designed for cell E5 of your fourth sheet. $D5, $E$2 and $F$2 are all on this sheet.

`Counts1` is a named range on Sheet1, comprising all the passenger counts, starting from column E, up to the last day of the month and, vertically, from row 4 to as many rows as there are stations.

`Stops1` is another named range on Sheet1 D4:[end of column].

`Dates1` is a third named range on Sheet1, starting from E2:[end of row]. I would suggest you set up these named ranges to adjust dynamically to the actually used areas of the sheet.

Now, `INDEX(Counts,MATCH($D5,Stops,0),0)` defines all cells in the row of `Counts` where the *Stop* is equal to D5. Of course, this reference changes as you copy the formula down.

`SUMIFS` takes that range, extracts and sums up the numbers you are interested in.

Now, if you need to extract the same numbers by the same system from 3 different sheets you simply repeat the formula 3 times, concatenating the results with plus signs. That leaves you with the task to set up 9 ranges instead of only 3, each group of 3 on one of your source sheets. By the system I have implied above you would name them `Count2`, `Count3` etc.

That leaves the question of your dates. They must be true dates. Text strings that look like dates won't do. (I guess you know that :-). In the test sheet I set up I entered `=DATE(2020,3,1)` in E2, [F2]`=E2+1` and copied from F2 to the right.

Comment: Ok, I understand the formula but it returns 0, I double check and my value are in date format

Comment: I tested the formula. It works. Therefore the fault is in your setup. Troubleshoot your formula. Start by testing your named ranges. `=Stops1`, `=SUM(Counts1)`, `=Dates`, `=INDEX(Dates, 1,3) < INDEX(Dates, 1, 14)`, `= MATCH($D5, Stops, 0)`, `SUM(INDEX(Counts,MATCH($D5,Stops,0),0))`, '=SUMIFS(E7:K7,Dates1,">=" & $E$2,Dates1,"<=" & $F$2)`, this sort of thing. Look for unexpected results. Don't forget to check if the value you have in D5 contains a typo or the values in E2:F2 aren't dates perhaps.